# INSERT INTO WHERE LIKE Condition

Tags: mysql

I am working on a trigger which needs INSERT INTO with WHERE LIKE logic.

I have one table :
Tabel test;

> idDocument = varchar(32) idUnit = varchar(3)

```
-----------------------------
|  idDocument | idUnit      |
-----------------------------
|  AA/2021/KK |   NULL      |
|  AA/2021/JJ |   NULL      |
|  BB/2021/KK |   NULL      |
|  CC/2021/JB |   NULL      |
-----------------------------
```

How to `INSERT INTO` using `WHERE LIKE Condition` and myquery still ERROR.

myquery :

```
INSERT INTO test ('idUnit') Values ('111') WHERE idDocument LIKE
'%KK%'
```

Comment: Formatting a bit of a wreck here. I tried to tame it, but you may need to add a little more detail here, like in particular, can you add the *exact* error text you're getting?

Comment: INSERT INTO creates new rows and do nothing with existing ones. You need in UPDATE.

Comment: Tip: MySQL uses a variety of quotes, and you must be aware of the purpose of each kind. Pay extremely close attention in examples.

Comment: using UPDATE but not show into PHP

Comment: Error. Text. Please. Focus. MySQL is very good at explaining the exact problem, though you do need to be familiar with how to read the output, which is where we're trying to help.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE idDocument LIKE '%KK%'' at line 1

Comment: You can't add a `WHERE` clause to an `INSERT`. You can, and probably *should* to an `UPDATE`, which you said you tried, so you should update to include that code.

Comment: @Andina *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax* Of course, `INSERT .. VALUES` syntax does not allow WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally to update *existing rows* with a new value you'd do something like this:

```
UPDATE test SET idUnit='111' WHERE idDocument LIKE '%KK%'
```

This will not insert data, it will only *alter existing data*.

Note:

- `INSERT` is *specifically* for **adding new rows of data**
- `UPDATE` is *exclusively* for **updating existing rows with new data**

You can't conditionally add new rows. You either add them or you don't. You *can* conditionally update or delete them.

Don't think about it in terms of inserting new data, always think in terms of *rows* and *columns* which is how SQL works.